# Mysql InnoDB vs Mongodb write performance

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I need to increment a counter each time a web page is rendered.

- When I use mongodb to do that, I can do about 16000 writes per second on a 4 cores/8 threads CPU on a regular disk.
- When I use Mysql InnoDB table, I can do only... 30 writes per second on regular disk or 200 writes on SSD !!

Because I have only one write per transaction (basically I have no other write to do after incrementing my counter for a same http request)
Using autocommit to False and manually commit will not help.

The différence is that Mongodb flushes writes lazyly.

I tried to have Mysql buffering writes before flushing them to disk by setting these parameters into my.cf, but it did not helped :

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_change_buffering=all
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
```

Is there a way to have faster mysql writes ?

Comment: Voting to close this as off topic, since it belongs to http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: does that mean all mysql and mongodb questions are now off topic onto S.O ?

Comment: Just the questions closer related to db administration (configuration in this case) than to programming. Four other people have to agree with me though for this question to be put on hold, though.

Comment: May be it was a programatic misconception of my own...

Comment: `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2` should make your queries a lot faster, it will not make flush on every transaction end, but only each 1 - 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

Is the winner : 150x faster !!! on standard disk (will try on SSD later)

Comment: Nothing is free. You are trading durability for performance, see this [blog](http://tqdev.com/2016-trading-durability-for-performance-without-nosql)

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is "increment a counter each time a web page is rendered" then I suggest you ditch the database for this altogether. Keep the counter purely in memory (for example via `memcached`), and use a cronjob to dump it to disk every 10 mins to keep a more permanent record.

If you're recording more than just a counter and want to use a database, consider using the MySQL `MEMORY` storage engine (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html).

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

The table will be kept in memory so will be much faster than a disk based table. You'll just need a script to do a manual 'flush' to disk (e.g. `mysqldump`) from time to time if you need the permanence.